# get value back of array number in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 395
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 395
    [3] => 395
    [4] => 39
    [5] => 17
    [6] => 11
    [7] => 35
    [8] => 21
    [9] => 11
    [10] => 11
    [11] => 0
    [12] => 0
    [13] => 0
    [14] => 0
    [15] => 0
    [16] => 0
    [17] => 375
    [18] => 0
    [19] => 0
    [20] => 0
    [21] => 0
    [22] => 22
    [23] => 215
    [24] => 215
    [25] => 42
    [26] => 163
    [27] => 163
    [28] => 61
    [29] => 61
    [30] => 134
    [31] => 134
)
```

Now, i get the maximum Value of that array with this code :

```
echo max($similar);
```

For the array i said, the output will be : `395` that is in the `array[0]` and `array[2]` and `array[3]`.

Now, i want to know How can i give this number (395) and get the location of that in the array ?

For example,

I need a function like this :

```
echo_value_from_num(395); // Output :: 0
```

The output is zero, mean first time 395 appeard in the [0] of array.

How we can get that number in the array with that Values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `array_serach` (https://www.php.net/array_search) will return the key for a certain element.

In your example, it would be something like this:

```
$max = max($similar);
$key = array_search($max,$similar);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the locations (keys) with the highest values,

```
$max = array_keys($array, max($array));
```